# MySQL: LEFT JOIN + Alias

Tags: mysql

Consider the table `table1` and its corresponding lookup table `table2`:

```
`table1`
a b
1 11
2 22
3 33
4 44
5 55

`table2`
b c
11 111
22 222
33 333
44 444
55 555
```

You can perform a lookup between `table1` and `table2` with the following query:

```
SELECT `table1`.`a`, `table1`.`b`, `table2`.`c`
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2`
ON `table1`.`b` = `table2`.`b`
```

Which would correctly prompt the result:

```
a b c
1 11 111
2 22 222
3 33 333
4 44 444
5 55 555
```

**Issue**
Now, suppose that for some reason you need an alias for column b (ex: some function calculation). Instinctively you might try to execute the following query:

```
SELECT `table1`.`a`, ABS(`table1`.`b`) as tb, `table2`.`c`
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2`
ON tb = `table2`.`b`
```

However, MySQL would said:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'tb' in 'on clause'
```

**Question**
What is wrong in the query above? How to correct it?
How to use aliases in `LEFT JOIN` queries?

Comment: @Strawberry Suppose the longhand is far painful to be used. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @Strawberry _"The type of JOIN is immaterial"_ mind to explain what this means?

Comment: @Strawberry _"you cannot reference column aliases in this way."_ Why not? What is the 'rule' to know what is write and what is wrong?

Comment: @Strawberry _"it's almost always more efficient to use the longhand"_ This happens because the accepted answer used 2 `SELECT` clauses instead of one? Or simpler aliases that do not change that much the structure of the  query also decrease significantly de performance?

Comment: @Strawberry `SELECT 1+1 AS b WHERE b = 2; ERROR` Let me see if I get right; aliases can not be the result of some calculation? They must be values already calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At same level of query you can't use column aliases in `ON` clause however you can use the complete expression of alias in `ON` clause

```
SELECT `table1`.`a`, ABS(`table1`.`b`) as tb, `table2`.`c`
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2`
ON ABS(`table1`.`b`) = `table2`.`b`
```

Edit to use aliases in `ON` clause you can use them in outer query like

```
SELECT a.`a`, a.tb, b.`c`
FROM(
    SELECT `a`, ABS(`b`) as tb FROM `table1`
) a
LEFT JOIN `table2` as b
ON a.tb = b.`b`
```

Comment: @MarkMessa I have updated my post see how you can use your aliases

Comment: Since there are more `SELECT` clauses, is there any performance reduction using this 2nd statement instead of the 1st one?

Comment: @MarkMessa Yes performance can be affected for such type of queries

Comment: @MarkMessa Its not a simple alias see the operations you are performing on the column and then using this calculated column you are joining another table moreover if you try to index the column which is used in calculation then index will not be utilized that is how queries work